# R shiny remove UI keeps the label

Tags: r, shiny

I am calling shiny removeUi() for an textInput, however, only the input section gets removed and not the label. See code and image below:

```
clearElements <- function (dat) {
    observe({
      for (el in dat) {

        id <- strsplit(el,substring(el, nchar(el)-8, nchar(el)))[[1]]
        print(id)
        removeElement(id)
      }
    })
  }

  removeElement <- function (el_id) {
      removeUI(
        selector = paste0("#", el_id),
        multiple = TRUE,
        immediate = TRUE,
        session
      )
  }
```

Here is the visual result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer does not work.

You need to remove the entire .shiny-input-container like below

```
removeUI(
    selector = sprintf('.shiny-input-container:has(#%s)',el_id)
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

Several elements are wrapped in `div`s. Try this instead:

```
removeElement <- function (el_id) {
    removeUI(
       selector = paste0("div:has(> #", el_id, ")")
      )
    }
```