# removeUI does not remove UI completely

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have two tabItems in my dashboard as following in the ui.r file:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Title"
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = FALSE,
                   sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebarMenu',
                               menuItem('Tab 1', tabName = 'tab1'),
                               menuItem('Tab 2', tabName = 'tab2')
                   )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1",

              div(id = "panel1_tab1",
                  wellPanel(title = "",
                            fluidRow(
                              column(4, actionButton("button_tab1","Check In Value",width='100%')
                              )
                            )
                  )
              ),

              div(id = "panel2_tab2",
                  wellPanel(title = "",

                            fluidRow(
                              column(8,
                                     textInput("valInput1", label = "Enter Input", value = "",width='100%')
                              )
                            )
                  )
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab2",

              div(id = "panel1_tab2",
                  wellPanel(title = "",
                            fluidRow(
                              column(4, actionButton("button_tab2","Check In Value",width='100%')
                              )
                            )
                  )
              ),

              div(id = "panel2_tab2",
                  wellPanel(title = "",
                            fluidRow(
                              column(8,
                                     textInput("valInput2", label = "Enter Input", value = "",width='100%')
                              )
                            )
                  )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

My intent is that: in each tab, if the user clicks the button, the textInput box in the other tab should be removed completely. Here is my code in server.r

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$button_tab1,
               {
                 removeUI(selector = '#valInput2')
               }
  )

  observeEvent(input$button_tab2,
               {
                 removeUI(selector = '#valInput1')
               }
  )
}
```

However, although the textInput box gets removed, its label "Enter Input" still remains. How do remove this entire UI completely?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627257/r-shiny-remove-ui-keeps-the-label). I just adapted it to your case:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Title"
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(collapsed = FALSE,
                   sidebarMenu(id = 'sidebarMenu',
                               menuItem('Tab 1', tabName = 'tab1'),
                               menuItem('Tab 2', tabName = 'tab2')
                   )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(

      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab1",

              div(id = "panel1_tab1",
                  wellPanel(title = "",
                            fluidRow(
                              column(4, actionButton("button_tab1","Check In Value",width='100%')
                              )
                            )
                  )
              ),

              div(id = "panel2_tab1",
                  wellPanel(title = "",

                            fluidRow(
                              column(8,
                                     textInput("valInput1", label = "Enter Input", value = "",width='100%')
                              )
                            )
                  )
              )
      ),

      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "tab2",

              div(id = "panel1_tab2",
                  wellPanel(title = "",
                            fluidRow(
                              column(4, actionButton("button_tab2","Check In Value",width='100%')
                              )
                            )
                  )
              ),

              div(id = "panel2_tab2",
                  wellPanel(title = "",
                            fluidRow(
                              column(8,
                                     textInput("valInput2", label = "Enter Input", value = "",width='100%')
                              )
                            )
                  )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$button_tab1,
               {
                 removeUI(selector = sprintf('.shiny-input-container:has(#%s)','valInput2'))
               }
  )

  observeEvent(input$button_tab2,
               {
                 removeUI(sprintf('.shiny-input-container:has(#%s)','valInput1'))
               }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

PS: there is a typo in the name of the second panel in the first tab. I assume it is `panel2_tab1` instead of `panel2_tab2.`

Comment: Thanks, bretauv. Yes, it was a typo. I am looking to just remove the textInput box, not the whole wellPanel. I think I will just put ```label = NULL``` in order to avoid this problem. I couldn't find any posts that have solved this.

Comment: I edited my answer with an answer found online, it should work

Comment: I found that same solution. But it doesn't work (textInput box still showing). Did you try running that code?

Comment: the code I provided removes both the textInput and its label, not the grey area corresponding to the wellPanel

Comment: Yup, I am referring to the textInput and its label: they are still showing after clicking the button with that solution code. I want the wellPanel area to remain with empty grey space.

Comment: that's strange it works for me (you want the textinput in the second tab to disappear when you click on the button in the first tab and vice versa, right?), maybe you should check once more with the code in the post

Comment: OK, if I run the code from RStudio ```app.R``` file by clicking "Run App", it does not work. But if I copy the whole code into the RStudio console and run, it works? Wonder what is going on.

Comment: well, both work for me and it shouldn't behave differently, maybe restart R?